# Can I put images in an email using a text based email client?

Tags: email, images

Can I use a text-based email client to embed images in my emails?

Outlook is really inefficient and it drives me crazy. But I'd still have to embed emails.

Comment: Using Base-64 maybe?

Comment: Possible, sure... with `telnet mailserver 25` and enough time, I'm sure you can get even a multi-part encoded message containing embedded images to go through. What mail client do you plan on using? Have you checked if it supports this feature?